# Tenable API with JSON request object Integration error

Tags: java, nessus

I'm having this error when running the following code (it's not full).
The error is the following and I couldn't get past it so far:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:107)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:145)
    at tenablescscancreator.TenableSCScanCreator.getUUID(TenableSCScanCreator.java:141)
    at tenablescscancreator.TenableSCScanCreator.main(TenableSCScanCreator.java:80)
Scan created successfully. Response: {"type":"regular","response":"","error_code":13,"error_msg":"This request is not properly formatted.","warnings":[],"timestamp":1686316237}
```

The code is:

```
public class TenableSCScanCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String baseUrl = "Internal Nessus Server Link";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";

        String scanName = "zTestScan1";
        String policyName = "Full scan including web";
        String scanZone = "Default Scan Zone";
        String importRepository = "Active Vulns";
        String credentialsCategory = "Windows";
        String credentialsName = "NessusScan";
        String[] assetsList = {"asset1", "asset2"};

        /*try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            // Set up basic authentication
            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
            );*/
        try {
            CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient
                = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
        // Create scan request JSON
        
        String requestBody = String.format(
                "{ \"uuid\": \"%s\", \"settings\": [ \"name\": \"%s\", "
                + "\"policy\": \"%s\", \"scan_zone\": \"%s\", \"import_repositories\": \"%s\", "
                + "\"credentials\": [ \"category\": \"%s\", \"name\": \"%s\" ], "
                + "\"assets\": [ \"asset\": %s ], "
                + "\"starttime\": \"now\" ] }",
                getUUID(baseUrl, httpClient),
                scanName,
                policyName,
                scanZone,
                importRepository,
                credentialsCategory,
                credentialsName,
                getAssetsListJSON(assetsList)
        );
        
        // Send scan creation request
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(baseUrl + "/rest/scan");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        // Process response
        if (responseEntity != null) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseEntity.getContent()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuilder.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();

            System.out.println("Scan created successfully. Response: " + responseBuilder.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create scan.");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried replacing the braces with box brackets, but it still didn't work.

I tried replacing the braces in the JSON request with box brackets. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you should try pyTenable
Its way more simplier

https://pytenable.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/sc/scans.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).